java code to read table and pass values dynamically
I am trying to write java code  where i would like to form a statement like "select * from ABC where DIFFERENT CONDITIONS"

If there are DATE_START & DATE_END it should have SYNTAX "DATE
between '0' & '99210331'"
If there are TIME_START & TIME_END it
should have SYNTAX "TIME between '0' & '220000'"
If there is no
PREFIX _START & _END it should have SYNTAX  IN '2015'

EXAMPLE1



name
values




DATE_START
0


DATE_END
20230101


TIME_START
0


TIME_END
173000




If there are DATE_START & DATE_END it should have SYNTAX DATE between '0' & '20230101'
e.g.DATE between '0' & '20230101'
If there are TIME_START & TIME_END it should have SYNTAX TIME between '0' & '173000'
e.g.TIME between '0' & '173000'

so in this example it should be
"select * from ABC where DATE BETWEEN '0' & '20230101' AND TIME BETWEEN '0' & '173000' ;"
EXAMPLE2



name
values




DATE_START
0


DATE_END
20230101


TIME_START
0


TIME_END
173000


YEAR1
2015


YEAR2
2016


ACDAT_START
20200101


ACDAT_END
20200202



so in this example it should be
"select * from ABC where DATE BETWEEN '0' & '20230101' AND TIME BETWEEN '0' & '173000' AND YEAR1 IN '2015' AND YEAR2 IN '2016' AND ACDAT BETWEEN '20200101' AND '20200101' ;"
Please suggest how to write java code to pass values dynamically and taking certain prefixes from name.

Two things: what does If there are mean? And secondly, of course your conditions are not valid SQL - it's  AND, not &. Also what does this mean? it should have SYNTAX IN '2015' Do you mean that the datetime should truncate to the year being equal to 2015? You need to specify exactly what your input is

This is a rewrite of this question from yesterday but at least there are no longer images of data.

I recommend that you remove the double quotes and bold format and instead use [code block] format for readability. SQL is code. But the main problem is that this is not a valid question for [so]. This is not a code for free site. As it is now is off-topic. What have you tried? What didn't work? What is preventing you of implementing it yourself?

I've removed the dynamic-programming tag, since the question has nothing to do with it (see the tag description for what it should be used for).

So far this question as it stands is not showing any java code the question asked is based on and therefore fails to show any effort. Based on the sql you show in the question you should be better off trying to work out the actual working sql queries using your database development tool on your local database. If the sql statements work in your database development tool then you might consider coming back here to ask a question about writing java code to produce such statements.

Put your parameters in a map Map<String, String> and group them using the substring before the underscore (_) and get a Map<String, Map<String, String>>. Stream over the grouped maps and add your clauses checking if any of the keys ends with _START or _END. Since a standard map doesn't allow duplicate keys, if your YEAR1 or YEAR2 params can have multiple values add them as a comma separated values. Example:
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> paramsExample1 = Map.of("DATE_START", "0",
                                                    "DATE_END", "20230101",
                                                    "TIME_START", "0",
                                                    "TIME_END", "173000",
                                                    "YEAR1", "2015",
                                                    "YEAR2", "2016",
                                                    "ACDAT_START", "20200101",
                                                    "ACDAT_END", "20200202" );

        Map<String, String> paramsExample2 = Map.of("DATE_START", "0",
                                                    "DATE_END", "20230101",
                                                    "TIME_START", "0",
                                                    "TIME_END", "173000");

        Map<String, String> paramsExample3 = Map.of("DATE_START", "0",
                                                    "DATE_END", "20230101",
                                                    "TIME_START", "0",
                                                    "TIME_END", "173000",
                                                    "YEAR1", "2015, 2016, 2017",
                                                    "YEAR2", "2016, 2019");


        System.out.println(createQuery(paramsExample1));
        System.out.println(createQuery(paramsExample2));
        System.out.println(createQuery(paramsExample3));
    }

    private static String createQuery(final Map<String, String> params) {
        return "SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE " +
               params.entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().split("_" )[0],
                                                    Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)))
                     .entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .map(e -> addClause(e)).collect(Collectors.joining(" AND " )) + ';';
    }

    private static String addClause(Entry<String, Map<String, String>> e) {
        return e.getValue().keySet().stream().anyMatch(k -> k.endsWith("_START" )) ?
               e.getKey() + " BETWEEN '" + e.getValue().get(e.getKey() + "_START" ) + "' AND '" + e.getValue().get(
                       e.getKey() + "_END" ) + '\'' :
               e.getKey() + " IN (" + e.getValue().get(e.getKey()) + ")";
    }
}

